# How to check DST status for specified timezones

Tags: vb.net, timezone, dst

I would like to check if any specified timezone (other than my local time zone) is in DST or not.

To check if the local time zone is currently DST I am using:

```
Dim today_date As Date = Now.Date
Msgbox(today_date.IsDaylightSavingTime())
```

I would like to check if other time zones ("A.U.S. Eastern Standard Time" and "New Zealand Standard Time") are in DST according to today's date.

So what I have so far:

```
Dim AusZoneId As String = "A.U.S. Eastern Standard Time" 
Dim AusZone As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(AusZoneId)
MsgBox(AusZone.SupportsDaylightSavingTime) 
'Established True or False if TZ supported DST
```

What I want to do is feed in a date (eg today) and see if this date according to AUS Eastern Standard time is in DST.

Comment: `"A.U.S. Eastern Standard Time"` is not a valid Windows time zone identifier.  It should be without the periods, as in `"AUS Eastern Standard Time"`.  The keys need to match *exactly* the IDs found in the registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I took my values from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912391%28v=winembedded.11%29.aspx

Comment: Yeah, that list is quite old.  Windows Embedded POS 1.1.  Also, those were names, not IDs.  The IDs from that era were numbers, but those are no longer in use anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't do it for a *date*, as that can be ambiguous (the start of the day in standard time and the end of the day in daylight time, or vice versa) but instead ask whether a specific point in time is in daylight time:

```
Dim zoneId As String = "AUS Eastern Standard Time";   
Dim zone As TimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId)
Dim dst As Boolean = zone.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.UtcNow)
```

(Or use some other point in time, of course.) I'd strongly encourage you to pass in a `DateTime` with a `Kind` of `Utc`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Agreed, definitely makes sense to use a DateTime rather than Date.